# select some records and then update them simultaneuosly in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, select, sql-update

I am developing a webservice in which I am fetching some records with select statement based on status and then I need to change the status.

Its like:

```
select * from tblx where status='x'
```

and then

`update  tblx set status='y' where status='x'` for the records fetched.

sample code:

```
 string getpaid = "select top2 * from tblfameface where img_f_p='paid'";
                con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1);
                con1.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getpaid, con1);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt1);

                foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    string updatepaid = "update tblfameface set img_f_p='free' where img_f_p='paid' ";
                    con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1);
                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(updatepaid, con1);
                    int temp = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con1.Close();
                }
}
```

I have no idea how to solve it.

Can I get any help??

Comment: what u have tried..and remove "frm" from update query..

Comment: @Rahul-actually I have no idea from where to start.

Comment: actually what you want a code or a way..and what's the error or intrupt you found.

Comment: ya or Anything to achieve this.

Comment: i have told you that it's ok just correct your update query.

Comment: What exactly you want, you already written query means you know how to do that, you want code?

Comment: @Rahul- the problem is, I want to update only those records which are fetched through select statement and If i will write update query as in the question, it will update all the records having status='x'. Am I right?

Comment: @Popeye- Please see my recent comment.

Comment: @Dear Khushbu it's really very confussing if u r getting a data from select query and use that value into ur update query.actually u r getting status = x records so instead of select query directly run your update query according to status x.why u r executing select query.Select query has no mean here.

Comment: @Rahul-ok see I pasted some code in question.

Comment: @khushbu if you want to update only those records that you have fetched from select query then see my updated answer.In just one query you will be able to select and update records..thanks

Comment: @khushbu No need to write a seperate select query in your problem just use your select query inside update query as i did.just see my answer again.i m gonna update it again..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28807/discussion-between-rahul-and-khushbu)

Comment: @Khushbu have you solved your problem or still struggling...

Comment: @Rahul requirement changed..so no need to worry.

Comment: @Khushbu ok that's gud but even you must accept my answer because you know it's the solution of your first problem that you have asked.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Prototype is ok except your "Update" query.Rewrite your update query like

```
update tblx set status='y' where status=(select status from tblx where status='x');
```

**As per your requirement:**

```
string updatepaid = "update tblfameface set img_f_p='free' where img_f_p=(select top 2 img_f_p from tblfameface where img_f_p='paid')";
con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1);
con1.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(updatepaid, con1);
int temp = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
con1.Close();
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: string getpaid = "update tblfameface set img_f_p='free' where img_f_p=(select TOP 2 * from tblfameface where img_f_p='paid')";

Comment: not * use img_f_p ,,only run that part and forget about select query part that you have write on your question..

Answer (score 0):

Here Your update statement is wrong:

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET <Column> = <New Value> WHERE <Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can just execute a single update statement like below.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET status='Y'
WHERE status='X'
```

Comment: please read the question again, its not just update I need to perform, first I want to fetch records then update only those records.

Comment: see whatver condition you apply to fetch records,the same condition you can use to update.

Answer (score 0):

Please, be more specific. Are you having problems with sql or c# ?

This could be helpful for C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b.aspx

and this for sql:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score -1):

update tblx set status='y' where status='x';

Comment: In my question I just wrote the prototype I want to develop.